# How do I uninstall Ubuntu OS (used Ubuntu for Windows)?

Tags: firefox, windows-7, uninstall

I wanted to try out Ubuntu, but I really don't like it.

How do I delete/uninstall and revert back to my previous Windows 7?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92707/how-do-i-remove-wubi

Answer (score 1):

For that i need to how did you install it? If you installed it using wubi then just login in window7, goto control panel>Programs&featues then uninstall ubuntu.

If you install it using partition then

```
1. If you install ubuntu by replacing the C drive of windows then just reinstall windows and create a new primary partition by deleting ubuntu partition.

2. If you install ubuntu in different partition then also re-install windows7 in C and format the ubuntu partition from windows Disk management (control Panel> Disk management or device management [not sure])
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you 
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/nongeeks-guide-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-dualbooting-machine/

but may i know what makes you to uninstall Ubuntu ? If its because of some OS problem then we can help you to solve it .

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference