# How to uninstall WUbi installed in E drive?

Tags: wubi, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92707/how-do-i-remove-wubi)
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

I am having Ubuntu installed in my E drive (Note: Not C drive) for over a year while I use window 7. For some reason, I want to format E drive, so I feel the need to uninstall Ubuntu first. The problem is that the option neither appears in Control panel nor is the `uninstall-wubi.exe` doing anything.

So help me to uninstall Ubuntu completely, manually. Also I don't want the option for selecting between Windows 7 and Ubuntu at boot time once I uninstall it.

Answer (score -3):

In Windows Device Management identify the partition where linux or ubuntu is installed including swap partition,delete the partitions.Then boot from windows CD/DVD, choose repair, in System Recovery Option,click command prompt run the following command one by one
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
Remove the CD from CD/DVDdrive and restart. Before doing the above it will be better to backup windows.

Comment: He has installed Wubi so no separate partitions are involved.