# What happens to the storage capacity when I uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, uninstall, disk-usage, storage

I used the wubi installer for Ubuntu 12.04.

After having trouble with getting the Ubuntu to boot, I tried uninstalling it with Wubi.

From 'My Computer' (in Windows 7), I noticed the maximum capacity of my hard drive drop from 256GB to 238GB.

I have tried using some methods with the command prompt to locate the missing storage, but Windows now only recognizes that the storage on the disk to have 238GB instead of the original 256GB.

Is there any way to recover that memory?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/92707/how-do-i-remove-wubi

Answer (score 0):

Files in Windows’ aptly named “shadow storage,” also known as “shadow copies,” don’t appear here. The shadow storage contains System Restore points and previous versions of files for the Previous Versions feature in Windows Explorer.

To view the exact amount of storage used by shadow files on every hard drive attached to your system, you can run the command below. You’ll need to run it as Administrator – to open a Command Prompt window as Administrator, search for Command Prompt in the Start menu, right-click the Command Prompt shortcut, and select Run as administrator.

Run the following command in the Command Prompt window:

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
```

To know more Why Do Hard Drives Show the Wrong Capacity in Windows visit [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/123268/windows-hard-drive-wrong-capacity/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the (main) reasons that Wubi Ubuntu installs stop working is the corruption of the virtual disk (`\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`). Typically what you see when you try to boot Ubuntu is the `grub>` prompt, because grub is still there, but when it fails to find the `root.disk` it can not proceed.

When the root.disk is corrupted (I am talking about NTFS corruption here), then when you boot Windows it may run `chkdsk` automatically and attempt to fix the file, in some cases recovering it to a hidden `\found.000` directory (or `\found.001` etc.), and renaming it to `file0000.chk` in the process.

So, in your case, if you had a 17GB Ubuntu install, then you might find a 17GB file sitting hidden away. If that's the case you can either recover data you may have lost, or simply delete the file to recover the space.

That's one possibility.

PS for specific discussion on how to recover the corrupted root.disk, or find it in the hidden directory, see [here](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html).