# "/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr" error

Tags: windows-7, wubi, uefi

I am having some problems with my new laptop ASUS N76VM.

I have read up on the problem for the past couple of days, as it seem to be UEFI related. First, I tried to use the WUBI installer and since then it seems to have left some sort of boot setup behind.

At every boot, even after formatting the partition I created for my Ubuntu install, I get to choose between Windows 7 or Ubuntu, but no matter what, if I choose to boot in Ubuntu I get a `/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr` error.

The WUBI failed due to the UEFI problem, my BIOS holds no setup to disable the EFI protocol, so after a while i tried to install the x64 12.10 version from the LiveUSB stick, and chose to boot in UEFI USB mode. This installed just fine for the first time, but on boot I still get the choice between Ubuntu and Windows 7, but when booting into Ubuntu, I get the `/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr` error right away.

Since the `/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr` error shows up along with the choice of booting into Ubuntu. even when nothing should be installed except windows 7, I would think that the WUBI installer have messed something up in the bootloader.

Anyone has any good ideas?

Comment: that did the job. thank you. at every reboot i get the selection screen with only one option. Windows 7. if i press ESC however, i get the option to boot into my Kubuntu install. so it worked sort of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WUBI uses **Windows bootloader** that needs to be reverted back to its previous state using Windows tools.

When Ubuntu is installed using Live USB, it uses its own bootloader called **GRUB**.

Use [How do I remove wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92707/how-do-i-remove-wubi) to fix Windows bootloader first.

Then you may have to fix GRUB using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair).

Look at [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) for detailed instructions on Ubuntu installation on UEFI computers with Windows 8. Some of it won't apply since you have Windows 7, but the rest may be useful.