# Ubuntu 12.10 Black Screen When Trying to Install

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I am currently using Windows 8. I tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 through the Windows Installer however upon restart of my computer when clicking on Ubuntu in GRUB I am told that Windows could not start because I'm missing `wubld.mbr` file. Something along those lines.

My question is how can I remove this Ubuntu boot option from GRUB (I've already tried command prompt `fix mbr` commands) and then, how do I get Ubuntu working on my machine!

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/239245/ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-error

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]If you have a Win8 disc you can possibly fix Windows, otherwise you might have to re-install Windows. Which I would do before trying to fix Ubuntu.[EDIT]

I would try re-installing Ubuntu. Though, try burning the .iso to a DVD and then install from that. If you're trying dual boot, choose "something else" when it comes time to select where to install, then choose the partition you had created the first time and write over the failed install. Otherwise, choose the first option, erase everything? Now, maybe there is another way, but to avoid possible headache, this is what I'd do.

Comment: No windows disk, is there a workaround?