# Windows won't boot File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Tags: wubi

I am really new to Ubuntu s i don't normally use it but i have to install it on my laptop for my computer course. My laptop runs on Windows 7 and it is pretty new. I downloaded and installed Ubuntu via Windows Installer from the website, however, when i restarted the computer and tried to boot the computer using Ubuntu, the following message appears:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To Fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
 2. Choose your language settings, and the click "Next."
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or manufacturer for assistance.

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
Status: 0xc0000098
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

As I said, I am really new to Ubuntu. I have searched up the issue and found some solutions but they sound quite complicate and I have no idea what to do. Can somebody help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @minerz029 exactly how that question is a dupe? It doesn't even talk about Windows 7 but windows 8.

Comment: Could be also dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/239245/169736

Answer (score 1):

You mention that your Windows 7 is pretty new. A few Windows 7 systems used the new UEFI (but no secure boot) with gpt partitioning where most used BIOS with MBR(msdos) partitioning. If you have gpt partitioning wubi will not install correctly.
Grub4dos (which wubi uses) doesn't work with GPT disks (required by UEFI)

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice

If you have an efi partition then you have gpt partitioning. If you just have the standard 100MB Windows boot partition and the main install with two recovery partitions, one Windows repairs and the other the Vendor image of your system then you have BIOS with MBR.

You do have to install wubi from inside Windows.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

If all you want to do is remove the wubi entry in the BCD use Windows bdcEdit to remove entry. See manually removing in WubiGuide for more info.