# Unable to open ubuntu

Tags: 13.04

I did Ubuntu 13.04 installation on windows 8 64 bit machine.The installation went fine but after booting when i select ubuntu OS it is saying boot error and system is not able to load file \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr..Kindly give me solution for this i need it on urgent basis

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't disable UEFI before installing Ubuntu on a Windows 8 system.
First remove Wubi by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92707/how-do-i-remove-wubi) link.
 Next fix the grub using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair).
 Check out the instructions on [how to install Ubuntu on Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) and reinstall it.