# How to remove Windows bootoption that results in 'wubildr.mbr'/0xc000007b error message?

Tags: wubi, windows-8, uefi

At one point I tried to install Ubuntu onto my hard drive without a USB or a CD. It is a Windows 8 computer. It didn't work, so I eventually gave up and did it with a USB. Ubuntu works fine now, but whenever I try to boot into Windows, asks me if I want to boot into Windows or UNetBootin. When I click UNetBootin, it gives me an error message:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the 
cause. To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows Installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer 
manufacturer for assistance.

    File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
    Status: 0xc000007b
    Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a 
          required file is missing or contains error.
```

How do I get rid of the UNetBootin/Wubi option entirely?

Comment: did you by chance install a live distro to your hard disk using unetbootin? to get rid of that, just start up unetbootin after you boot up regularly to clear that out. You may be prompted "unetbootin is currently installed" would you like to uninstall it (or something similar) choose yes to uninstall it, reboot and repeat this process after rebooting to confirm the method was successful and if so, you will not receive a prompt when you open unetbootin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rather sounds like you tried to install Ubuntu with Wubi first and then did a real install from live media. (I don't see how UNetBootin is involved here until this point.)

So you seem to have two Ubuntu installations and the Wubi one does not boot (due to relying on legacy booting were UEFI booting is done - but I don't know much about this topic and am just guessing here).

If that is the case, which means that you can confirm that you:

1. Can boot Windows without errors.
2. Can boot Ubuntu without errors.

Then you should continue with:

- [How do I remove wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92707/40581)

Related question that explains more than necessary and troubleshoots issues that you already solved yourself:

- [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/40581)

For more details see the [tag info page of the Wubi tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info).